# Ancient greek roman characters

Tags: unicode, fonts

I have extracted the Greek text from pdf that give me the HTML output as :
μεταξ˜
where the last character is in the old greek font.
The **interesting** point here is that if i view it in the MS-word and select the last character to
the font as "OldGreekRoman" than that character is now viewable as to original form.

That is baffling me.Please help.

I need the original unicode of that last character

Comment: ˜ (tilde) is the desired character.

Comment: no, the character in the question is U+02DC SMALL TILDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *original* Unicode: the character was originally a custom glyph in a symbol font. It has no semantic meaning—it's like the letter ‘A’ looking like a peace sign in Wingdings.

What is the glyph supposed to look like? There might or might not be a Unicode character that represents the same letter. It *might* be possible to create a mapping from symbols in the “OldGreekRoman” font to Unicode equivalents, or the font may be for characters that don't exist in Unicode; I can't tell without a copy of the font.

Comment: The Downloadable link for that font is: http://www.vanderbilt.edu/AnS/religious_studies/SNTShome.htm

Comment: OK, it looks like that font consists of precomposed glyphs for extended polytonic accents which can be written in Unicode. For example the glyph associated with latin `a` is `ᾇ`, U+1F87 Greek small letter alpha with dasia and perispomeni and ypogegrammeni. It should be a straightforward but long and boring task to come up with a mapping table for all the glyphs in the font.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is way off-topic here and should be moved elsewhere, I cannot resist the temptation to answer that with the given information about context, which is about void, the most probable answer is that the SMALL TILDE character is the result of some character munging of the letter U+03CD GREEK SMALL LETTER UPSILON WITH TONOS, “ύ”. The reason is that “μεταξύ” is a real Greek word.

Comment: Thats right but is there any right way to get the right unicode i.e. 03cd not tilde

Comment: In MS Word, you can type `u+3cd` and then press Alt X to get U+03CD.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of characters in your question:

> μεταξ˜

is:

- 03bc GREEK SMALL LETTER MU
- 03b5 GREEK SMALL LETTER EPSILON
- 03c4 GREEK SMALL LETTER TAU
- 03b1 GREEK SMALL LETTER ALPHA
- 03be GREEK SMALL LETTER XI
- 02dc SMALL TILDE

That last character is not specifically Greek.

This assumes the characters were correctly copy-and-pasted into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the character *from the original pdf* and paste it into [this web app](http://unicodelookup.com) and you will see what the unicode code point is.